# C# winforms return empty form when i open as dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have problem when i try to show dialog. When i pass `this` argument as parameter form is empty.

What i do:

In my `GroupsForm.cs` form i create this method:

```
   private void addGrupuBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var add = new GroupAdd(this))
        {
            add.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

In `GroupAdd.cs` form i try to inject `GroupsForm.cs` via constructor

```
    public partial class GroupAdd : Form
    {
        private GrupeForm grupeForm;

        public GroupAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public GroupAdd(GrupeForm groups) { 
            grupeForm = groups;
        }
  }
```

When i call default constructor without `this` all controls inside form is rednered.

This work ok.

```
using (var add = new GroupAdd())
```

Comment: Your second constructor doesn't call InitializeComponent quite obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `InitializeComponent()` in your constructor, that's why it doesn't work.

Modify your code to this:

```
    public GroupAdd(GrupeForm groups) { 
        grupeForm = groups;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: I have another constructor for that. Default costructor is first  which is initialize components

Comment: Yes, but you don't call the default constructor, so components won't be initialized.

Comment: Wait i dont vote down. Is okay working i will mark as sloved

Answer (score 3):

You should call parameterless (default) ctor as well to initialize your controls.

```
public GroupAdd(GrupeForm groups)
    : this()
{ 
    grupeForm = groups;
}
```